# Mac OS 10.15 Catalina: where is the first time boot presentation of new features stored?

Tags: macos

where do I find the presentation of the new features of macOS that is automatically displayed after booting the computer for the very fist time?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the "Welcome to MacOS" Setup Wizard?

Comment: @benwiggy please answer if you know of a local copy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Finder, help menu > See what's new in macOS.

It takes one at: https://help.apple.com/macOS/mojave/whats-new/

Comment: Thanks anti, that's exactly what I meant. Apparently easy, if you know where to look! :-)
However, I thought there was a locally stored copy. The Internet link does the job as well